# Which is more efficient one document table or many document table

Tags: mysql

I don't know how can I explain this.
So just I show you the example.

## Type A

```
documents
 - board(varchar 30) : boardA | boardB | boardC
 - title(varchar 300)
 - content(longtext)
 ...
```

## Type B

```
boardA_documents
 - title(varchar 300)
 - content(longtext)
 ...

boardB_documents
 - title(varchar 300)
 - content(longtext)
 ...

boardC_documents
 - title(varchar 300)
 - content(longtext)
 ...
```

I think that Type A can be slow when very many documents are recorded.

But somebody tells me "It's not. It can be efficient by using index".

So I want to knows which is more efficient.

Comment: If you knows more efficient than both types, please let me knows it.

Comment: Definitely type A. Speed because of too many rows will likely not be an issue. You may wnat a separate `boards` table though, and a numeric `board_id` identifier to keep them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option A is more efficient.

with option B You need `UNION` to get all data back together.

Aditional tips.

- maybe `board_type` is a better name for that field.
- dont use text field for that, instead create int `board_type_id` field referencing another table board_type with

  - for example if you want change name for `boardA` to `boardA.1` you only have to change one row.

.

```
board_type_id board_type 
    1           boardA 
    2           boardB
    3           boardC
```

- create index for `board_type_id`

  - this will speed the search for each `board_type`